# Matching CSS RGB color values

Tags: javascript, css, regex, colors, replace

I have a problem with a piece of JS code. It is supposed to find all occurences of CSS colors values (`colorNames`, `#FFFFFF`, `#FFF`, `RGB`, `transparent`) from a given style declaration and replace them with a `span` element followed by the match itself.

Well, everything seems ok, except the RGB() ones which wasted already my entire day.

A small presentation and the code can be found on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YEEnE/8/). And here we have a preview with my problematic elements.

[image]

Thanks for your time and interest!

Comment: I think your question should more clearly explain that you're having trouble using a Regex to find a pattern like `rgb(x, y, z)`

Comment: nope, as you can see, in that huge Regex, I have four patterns for `rgb()`, most of them taken from stackoverflow.

Comment: Yes I can see that. But everything else works fine. So your problem lies with the specific RGB regexes. Look - http://jsfiddle.net/Pm8vV/ - just using those special regexes you found, it still doesn't work.

Comment: Even in your link, that little squares before `RGB()` still don't have any color... but because there is a square, that means regex work fine, I presume.

Comment: That was my point. **Only** including your RGB regexes, it doesn't work. That means you need to work on the RGB regexes. But you're right, it still matches something. If you simply put `console.log` in your replacer, you'd easily see what's matching. Look - http://jsfiddle.net/Pm8vV/1/ (watch your browser's console)

Comment: aham, I must admit you're right... let me invent something :)

Comment: Just trying to help you figure out what the problem is :)

Comment: ofc, I can see now that is something wrong with Regex expression, but can't find any solution :) @Loamhoof answer extract the RGB() definition, but in my jsFiddle, everything is wrong...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should handle any valid `rgb` or `rgba` values

```
var regex = new RegExp(
    "rgb\\((?:(?:\\s*\\d+\\s*,){2}\\s*\\d+|" +
    "(?:\\s*\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?%\\s*,){2}\\s*\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?%)\\s*\\)|" +
    "rgba\\((?:(?:\\s*\\d+\\s*,){3}|" +
    "(?:\\s*\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?%\\s*,){3})\\s*\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?\\s*\\)", "gi"
);
```

See [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/YEEnE/12/).

Answer (score 0):

The rgb function doesn't support the alpha argument (rgba does). Also, your regular expressions matching those functions don't work. I have to admit, it's too much of a pain to debug all those regex to match only one thing, so we'll try to make only one.
Try (not any check on the values):

```
/(rgb\((?:\s*\d{1,3}\s*%?\s*,?\s*){3}\))/gi
```

[Result](http://jsfiddle.net/Vry2H/).

**Edit:**
If you wish to check your values, we'll complicate a bit more this regex.

Comment: I really don't know why your Regex don't wanna work on `.replace()` and work like a charm on `.match()`... I just used `(rgb\\(.*?\\))` and now is OK. I really don't care to much about checking the values of basic colors because I use `rgb(x, y, z)` retrieved from the `document` DOM (if I have a wrong declaration in .CSS file, that declaration wont be found on DOM .styleSheets element). [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YEEnE/10/)

Comment: It does work ([jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YEEnE/11/)), you'd simply want to replace '\' by '\\' the way you do it. Furthermore, `.*?` could be a little risky, but I guess it wouldn't matter since you're assuming correct CSS.